# Is my pi capable of running this in 1080p?

Tags: streaming-video, web-browsers

I have a pi 4b running Raspbian. And with it I'm hoping to run a web app on a TV in fullscreen. This web app plays an embedded youtube playlist and also has a fair few JavaScript animations on it. I assumed it would run this with no issue, but to my surprise it was quite laggy. It has a wired connection with 500mbps download available to it...

I did some research and discovered 2 main things I should try:

- Enabling hardware acceleration
- Using H264ify for video decoding

Once I finally figured out how to run the browser with hardware acceleration, it didn't seem to make any difference. In fact it may have been a little worse. and I can't seem to use H264ify on any domain other than youtube.com.

My question is, Is this pi capable of running this smoothly in 1080p? or am I chasing a dead end? If it is possible, what else can I do to help improve the issue?

Comment: Can your youtube playlist be loaded into libreelec? https://libreelec.tv

Comment: Possibly... I'm not sure yet as to how that will help, what's your idea? The intention of the project is to use the pi as a signage device that just loops a playlist and some general data. However the web app is created by our team also. So if it's feasible we could do some changes on that side too if it would help performance.

Comment: So I looked it up. Looks like an OS to turn my pi into a media outlet, like kodi, is that right? So we've previously tried a firestick to do this also, but we still have similar issues running it. Is there a reason that running it on a pi would be better?

Comment: You say it's a 'web app' - is it being hosted somewhere with good connectivity?

Comment: Yes, it's hosted with Azure. The connectivity seems good. It works fine on PC's etc.